# Is this minimization problem NP-Complete ?

Tags: np, computational-complexity

We are given an $n\times (n+k)$ matrix $A,$ with entries in $\mathrm{GF}(2),$ of the form $A=(I_n|B)$ where $I_n$ is a $n\times n$ identity matrix where the matrix $B$ has no "zero" rows or columns.

The problem is to partition the columns of $A$ into at most $m$ subsets each of size at most $b$ such that the number of "critical subset's" is minimized, where a critical subset is a subset of the set of columns such that if we remove it from $A$ the reduced matrix has rank less than $n.$

The problem seems to be NP-Complete to me but I am not able to understand from which problem we should try to reduce.

The elaborate problem definition/relevant discussion can be found at:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/optimization-problem-for-a-parity-check-code.

I am defining it here in some abstract way. Also, I wanted to post it under the NP-Complete tag.

Comment: Are you sure you want B to have "*no* non-zero rows or columns"?

Comment: This question was also posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60322/is-this-minimization-problem-np-complete

Comment: Prasenjit: to expand on Martin's remark, it is considered extremely poor form to post identical questions on MO and SE at the same time. The recommended course of action is to post it on SE, and then only repost on MO after about a week, if it looks like the SE question is going nowhere.

Comment: @Martin and Thierry: Sorry for posting it twice. I will keep in mind what you have said next time I post.

Comment: @Prasenjit: I assume that Francois interpreted "no non-zero rows or columns" the same way I did, which would mean that B is the zero matrix.  (A row or column (or any other sort of vector) is non-zero if at least one entry is non-zero.)  I also assume that you meant something else.  Please tell us what you meant.

Comment: @all: Sorry, I typed it wrongly. It will be B has no "zero" rows or columns. Thanks for pointing that. I changed that in the main question.

Comment: If I refine problem like this: How much of the n+k columns can be covered using m subsets each of size atmost b then I think it is possible to formulate it as a maximum independent set problem. We will form a graph of n+k vertices where each vertex corresponds to one column but the definition of edges is not clear to me (this is the main problem I am trying to solve). Then the maximum independent set of this graph will give us the maximum subset (of the n+k columns) that can be covered.

Comment: The reason I think that the problem is np-complete is that here without checking all possible combinations it is very difficult to find the optimum config. What do you think about the np-completeness of this problem? 